# Powershell saying storage account doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

In powershell I verify that it exists by calling the context.

```
New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "testdisks401" -StorageAccountKey "...."
```

Result

```
StorageAccountName : testdisks401
BlobEndPoint       : https://testdisks401.blob.core.windows.net/
TableEndPoint      : https://testdisks401.table.core.windows.net/
QueueEndPoint      : https://testdisks401.queue.core.windows.net/
FileEndPoint       : https://testdisks401.file.core.windows.net/
Context            : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext
Name               :
StorageAccount     : BlobEndpoint=https://testdisks401.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://testdisks401.queue.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://testdi
                 sks401.table.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://testdisks401.file.core.windows.net/;AccountName=testdisks401;AccountKey=[key hidden]
EndPointSuffix     : core.windows.net/
```

When I try to set it here:

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'XXXX' -CurrentStorageAccount "testdisks401"
```

I get this

```
Set-AzureSubscription : ResourceNotFound: The storage account 'testdisks401' was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'XXX
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureSubscription], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureSubscriptionCommand
```

Been stuck for quite a while. I basically want to write shellscript to create a VM from an existing OS disc. I managed to create a copy of an existing disc using powershell (used context from first command to make it work). But now that I am trying to create the VM configuration using this:

```
 $vmI1 = New-AzureVMConfig -Name "TestRecover" -InstanceSize Small -AvailabilitySetName 'RDGW' -DiskName 'MY-OS-Disk-Name'
```

I get this error:

```
New-AzureVMConfig : Must specify MediaLocation or set a current storage account using Set-AzureSubscription.
At line:1 char:9
+ $vmI1 = New-AzureVMConfig -Name "TestRecover" -InstanceSize Small -Av ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureVMConfig], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.NewAzureVMConfigCommand
```

A [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/10453062-7a43-4702-9a53-9f4278ba8957/error-creating-vm-from-an-existing-disc-using-a-cmdlet-in-a-powershellscript?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) has already been provided for this which brought me here (stuck on missing storage account error).

Comment: Please check if the storage account you're using is a `Classic` storage account or `Azure Resource Manager` storage account. My guess is that the cmdlet `Set-AzureSubscription` uses one of the type and your storage account is of another type.

Comment: @GauravMantri The storage account is Azure Resource Manager type. I do not believe the Set-AzureSubscription differentiates between the types. Its documentation does not mention such a case to my knowledge (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn790376.aspx)

Comment: Or not I think that's the case. I created a classic storage account to test and that was the case. This is very weird. @GauravMantri Please add it as an answer for me to accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Set-AzureSubscription` Cmdlet expects the storage account specified via `-CurrentStorageAccount` parameter to be a classic storage account.

Please make sure that you're specifying a classic storage account's name and not a resource manager storage account's name.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Storage Account created using ARM, then you can use these commands:

```
$SubscriptionName = "MySubscription"
$StorageAccountName = "MyStorage"
$ResourceGroup = "MyResourceGroup"
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName | Select-AzureRmSubscription
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -AccountName $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup
$key = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -AccountName $StorageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup).Key1
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $key
```

Comment: yes, i use this ctx variable then as an input to the command Set-​Azure​Subscription .. and still i get same error as storage account could not be found. I would really love to see this working for ARM based model !

Comment: One very important thing that one can miss is that storage account name needs to be in small case. Each and every letter. May be because of the naming convention the storage account is not getting created at all. Could you check if that's the case. Also, I could help more if I could see some script snippet. I have personally used the above script and it works for sure.

Comment: after getting ctx i did following step 1. Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId 4ceb426a-1203-4adb-dc2-b95a372a9e0 -Context $Ctx  step 2. Add-AzureVhd –Destination <desturl>  -LocalFilePath D:\azure.VHD      step 2 gives following error on shell: Add-AzureVhd : ResourceNotFound: The storage account 'vmrg001disks388' was not found.
CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Hyak.Common.CloudException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.AddAzureVhdCommand

Comment: and i did set the  $StorageAccountName = "vmrg001disks388" .. all small letters

Comment: Aah..got your issue. It had me frustrated when I was working in this. Azure resources are divided into classic and ARM. You are using classic commands and most likely your storage account is in ARM. If you see my commands, its using Select-AzureRmSubscription and not Set-AzureSubscription. Also, Add-AzureVhd has and alternate Add-AzureRmVhd. check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/add-azurermvhd?view=azurermps-3.8.0

Comment: If you are using classic commands then create a classic storage account else use the RM powershell equivalent commands to access the ARM resources

Comment: I also see my answer downvoted around the same time you posted the comment. I'm also trying to win my vote back here. :D

Answer (score 1):

How did you create that storage account?

If you created it as an RM Account that would explain the error you are getting. Antohter option is that testdisks401 is on the same subscription as you are trying to set.

Try to do the following:

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'XXXX'
Get-AzureStorageAccount | ft StorageAccountName
```

this will get you a list of classic storage accounts (non RM) in the XXXX subscription.

And then do the same for the RM accounts like this:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionName 'XXXX'
Get-AzureRMStorageAccount | ft StorageAccountName
```

If the testdisks401 account is in the RM list, then you either need to switch to the RM model, or you need to create a new storage account with the classic model.

edit:
forgot to mention that new-azurestoragecontext, does not validate anything. Try to run the following:

```
New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "bla" -StorageAccountKey "askjlksdfjldskgfjflkjdsflksj"
```

it will also give you a nice context object that leads nowhere:

```
StorageAccountName : bla
BlobEndPoint       : https://bla.blob.core.windows.net/
TableEndPoint      : https://bla.table.core.windows.net/
QueueEndPoint      : https://bla.queue.core.windows.net/
FileEndPoint       : https://bla.file.core.windows.net/
Context            : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageC
Name               :
StorageAccount     : BlobEndpoint=https://bla.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoin
EndPointSuffix     : core.windows.net/
```